# Tkinter Python Image error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I"m confused as to why I'm getting this error. I have looked into the file specified in the error as well as done some research on PIL and the actual error. Any help would be appreciated. This code is an example code, it doesn't belong to me. I'm following a tutorial I'm trying to learn a new gui module for python.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
          Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

          self.parent = parent

          self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

          self.parent.title("Picture")
          self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

          Style().configure("TFrame", background="#333")

          bard = Image.open("test.jpg")
          bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bard)
          label1 = Label(self, image=bardejov)
          label1.image = bardejov
          label1.place(x=20, y=20)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x280+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enter code heremain()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/pics.py", line 36, in <module>
     main()
    File "C:/Python27/pics.py", line 31, in main
     app = Example(root)
    File "C:/Python27/pics.py", line 12, in __init__
     self.initUI()
    File "C:/Python27/pics.py", line 22, in initUI
     bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bard)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 116, in __init__
     self.paste(image)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 181, in paste
     import _imagingtk
    ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Tou ommited indent in `main()`.

Comment: I mean to reformat Your pasted code. To the problem - check Tkinter version.

Comment: why did some one add enter main code here im so confuesed

Comment: none of this make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."` is from Windows itself, and means that your PIL or Tkinter install doesn't work on your Windows version.

One potential cause for this is that you're using a version built with VS 2012 on Windows XP; see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx

Comment: I reinstalled the tkinter moudle and python and that seemed to fix it